# Keyboard goes blank when trying to type special character on iPhone

Tags: iphone, keyboard

I type Polish a lot on my iPhone, requiring special characters.  At some point, this started happening: when I try to type a special character, press and hold brings up the menu, but before I can get to the character, the keyboard goes blank, and I have to give up.  I think the phone vibrates once, and it seems like it happens when my finger slips a little off the row of characters.  A screenshot looks like this:[image]
What the hell is the phone trying to do, and how do I stop it?

**EDIT:** This is purely intuition, but I think this is supposed to be a feature, not a bug, though I admit, I cannot figure out what the feature is.

Comment: A reference for the "feature"   https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/iphone-6s-3d-touch/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's part of the new 3D Touch feature.  Try putting it on the "firm" setting and don't push too hard when trying to get special characters.

Comment: Or just turn this stupid and annoying feature off!

Answer (score 1):

iOS thinks you have touched the keyboard with two fingers to enable the virtual trackpad. It allows you to use the keyboard like a laptop trackpad and select type in a URL field with it, similar to using the magnifier in the URL field.